# Querying keys in a docs on mongoDB by prefix

Tags: mongodb

At the moment, i have this data in mongo

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("62021f4cbd7796d438622245"),
    "id" : "MyData",
    "Mode" : "txtx",
    "MinCost" : "0.2",
    "R:1" : "info1",
    "R:13" : "info2",
    "R:3" : "info3",
    "R:4 : "info4",
    "R:5" : "info5",
    "Cost" : "100"
}
```

I want to return back just the keys from this data that has prefix, for example, "R" or "R:1". Basically, want to return just the keys that matches a prefix that i'm giving.

Comment: Can you add your expected output please?

Comment: For examples, for "R:" prefix, I want to return just those keys from this doc"`````{
    "R:1" : "info1",
    "R:13" : "info2",
    "R:3" : "info3",
    "R:4 : "info4",
    "R:5" : "info5",
} `````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)
- [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/)
- [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)
- [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)
- [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)
- [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)
- [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)
- [`$regexFind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexFind/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        "$gte": [
          {
            $size: {
              "$filter": {
                "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"},
                "as": "s",
                "cond": { "$regexFind": { "input": "$$s.k", "regex": "R:1" } }
              }
            }
          },
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
            "as": "s",
            "cond": { "$regexFind": { "input": "$$s.k", "regex": "R:1" } }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W-X9DtzeNtL)

Comment: Yup, that's what i wanted. I'm a bit newbie to mongo, and not gonna lie, this is a little hard for me to understand, but i'll watch all the params there. Thanks :)

Comment: @SpecialUserThisTime I update my answer with all the operators' reference that I used. Hope you doing well. And it would be great if you can accept this answer.

Comment: Yesir, thanks. Have a great time and good luck!

Comment: +1, this is a really good answer buy I think you can even avoid the first `$match` since there is a `$filter` in `$replaceRoot` stage.